# Python DataFrame: count of occurances based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a Python Data Frame of teams and a place that they have achieved (1, 2 or 3)

| Team | place |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |

I want to manipulate the df to look like this below. So it is a count of how often a team has achieved each place.

| Team | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['Team'], df['place'])
```

or a simple `groupby`+`size` and `unstack`:

```
(df.groupby(['Team', 'place']).size()
   .unstack('place', fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
place  1  2  3
Team          
A      5  1  1
B      0  2  0
```

###### all as columns

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Team'], df['place'])
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  Team  1  2  3
0   A   5  1  1
1   B   0  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value counts for each group and then unstack the index. The rest is twiddling to get your exact output.

```
(df.groupby('Team')['place']
   .value_counts()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

Comment: I realized while posting that this is in fact a simple `crosstab` :p